# Проблемы с запуском Wordpress на Denwer

Tags: wordpress, denwer

Denwer скачан и установлен. Worpress тоже скачан. Папка сайта создана, файлы из скаченного worpress архива в неё добавлены. Когда открываю её на локальном сервере он выдает такое сообщение:

```
Warning: require(\__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\wordpresslesson\www\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '\__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in Z:\home\wordpresslesson\www\index.php on line 17
```

Вроде как проблема в том, что запрашиваемого файла нет в директории, но файл с таким названием есть и лежит в той же папке, что и индексный файл. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Скрин пришлите, что файл есть в нужной директории

Comment: https://sun9-3.userapi.com/Nbyt6VYp5fg1K16sXmrfUlifdsX7TkAqyrt5EQ/Oa07pXNOPjE.jpg

Comment: Проверьте права на папки и файлы